# After segue using Storyboard ID UINavigationController disappears

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, parse-platform

In my app where I use Parse.com framework, afer any operation for example `sign up` I would like to go to another sotyboard for example `login`, so I do this code:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil{
                // alert Error

            } else {

                let action = UIAlertController(title: "Congratulattion!", message: "Now yu can start chatting", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (alert) -> Void in

                let mainVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login") as! LogInViewController
                self.presentViewController(mainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

                })
                action.addAction(ok)
                self.presentViewController(action, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
```

afert this segue my `NavgationBar` disappears. My Application looks like that:

[image: My whole sotryboard]

[image: Navbar disappears after segue]

[image: Navbar exists before I sign up in app]

What Do I need to do, my `Navbar` doesn't disappear?

> Picture with error which I see after segue from `Sign Up App Chat` to `Welcome in Chat App` using `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signup", sender: self)`

[image: segue1]

[image: segue2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want to use the code `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login") as! LogInViewController`. It looks like you are going from your signup controller to the login controller in your code, so you might want to add a segue connecting those 2 in your storyboard, and if you make it a segue of type 'show', then the navigation bar will stay intact. Then you can call `performSegue` on this segue.

Comment: I was doing it, but Xcode receiving me an error all the time, that segue identifier doesn't exist, but it really exists. I had this code before: `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signup", sender: self)` So why, did I get an error? The segue identifier between `Welcome in Chat App` and `Sign Up Chat App` is "signup"

Comment: @PiterPan you're on the signup page when you want to perform the segue aren't you? I'm a little confused as to what controller you want to go to after the user signs up?

Comment: Looks like the VC that says "Welcome" has two segues outbound from it.  Can you post a picture from IB that shows those segues identifiers?  @Jacob, this is a good answer, but it should suggest explicitly that the OP does a `performSegue` on these 'show' type segues.

Comment: My bad, I want to go back to `Welcome in Chat App` from `SignUp to Chat App` I added pictures.

Comment: @PiterPan if you want to go back then you can call self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

Comment: ok, but in another case. When I woud like to go dirctly to `login to Chat App` what do I need to do?

Comment: @PiterPan if you want to go from register to login you will need to add another segue in your storyboard linking the two, as I said in my answer. And you will need to call performSegue on this new segue.

Comment: @Jacob now, everything works perfect! Big thanks for help!